# How to disable outlook security warning while sending emails programmatically through C# windows application without using 3rd party tools

Tags: c#, .net, windows, outlook

I have developed a Windows application in C# that sends bulk mail using Microsoft Office interop. Mails are sent properly but I want to disable the security warning from Microsoft Outlook that pops up before sending each mail. I want to disable it through code and not using any 3rd party application by changing in registry.

Comment: can you show the exact warning and some code that can help?

Answer (score 0):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook.

There are several ways for suppressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption).
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object.
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.

You can read more about all these ways on the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) page.

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved by going back to the code and changed the way it had been coded previously.
This link helped me in order to write the code which is trusted by Outlook.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/specific-security-considerations-for-office-solutions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019